# How can I obtain class props from url and store in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

so I am trying to pass params using route to a react component and also at the same time use Component class props. Here is what am doing

```
import { loadSchemes, } from '../../actions/schemes;

export class Schemes extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { match: { params } } = this.props;
    this.state = {
      client_id: params.pk,
    }
  }
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.loadSchemes();
  }
render(){
 return(
   <div>
    {this.props.schemes_list.map((scheme,index)=><p key={index}>{scheme}</p>)}
   </div>
  )
 }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  schemes_list: state.schemes,
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps,{ loadSchemes,})(Schemes);
```

And I have a url to this component as

```
<Route path="/client/:pk/schemes" component={Schemes}/>
```

The problem is I get an error *this.props.schemes_list is undefined* and *this.props.loadSchemes is undefined*

please help am using react-redux

Comment: import { loadScheme, } is singular and where are you passing "schemes_list" i cant see

Comment: that import is a typo they are both loadSchemes, let me edit the question, and also the schemes_list is from schemes reducer.

Answer (score 0):

Obviousely in component from where you call Scheme, you import { Schemes }, an unconnected component, instead of Schemes - default connected component. Please check it.

Comment: Thanks you so much, that's is what I was missing, works perfectly now.